# Filtering AJAX response in Select2 plugin with another AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm new to JS and got select2 in my new project and at the moment I have code like this (this is a bit simplified version) which works just fine:

```
  $("#group-search").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "groups.search",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          q: term,
          access_token: access_token
        };
      },
      results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data.response.items };
      }
    }
  });
```

but I need to filter my results (`data.response.items`) with the help of another AJAX-request. Is it possible to achieve somehow?

**UPDATE 1**

This is what I've tried to do according to [ValLenain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3410584/vallenain)
 proposal but it doesn't work:

```
  results: function (data, page) {
    var groups = data.response.items;

    var groupIds = new Array;
    groups.forEach( function (group) {
      groupIds.push(group.id);
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: "groups.getById",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        group_ids: groupIds,
        v: '5.60',
        access_token: access_token
      },
      success: function(data, page) {
        return { results: data.response };
      }
    }).then(function(response){
      groups = []; 
// so at this moment we are expecting the select field to become empty, right?
// it doesn't work that way, nothing changes
    });

    return { results: groups };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried but changing your `results` function with the ajax call may work if you first return an empty array and update it in the ajax call.

```
results: function (data, page) {
  var items = [];

  /* Since I don't know what your ajax call is nor
  * what it takes as arguments or returns, I just write
  * a fake one.
  */
  ajaxCall(data.response.items).then(function(filteredItems) {
    /* update here the items array
    * it's important to change the existing object, not
    * to create a new one
    */
  });
  return { results:items };
}
```

**Regarding your Update 1**

You're changing the object referenced by the `groups` variable and so, what you've returned previously (`data.response.items`) won't get updated.

I've rewritten the body of the function

```
/* Set groups to an empty array so the select2
* component will never display unfiltered value.
*/
var groups = [];

var groupIds = new Array;
data.response.items.forEach(function (group) {
  groupIds.push(group.id);
});

$.ajax({
      url: "groups.getById",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        group_ids: groupIds,
        v: '5.60',
        access_token: access_token
      },
      success: function(data, page) {
        /* Here I assume your items are in data.response.items.
        * We push all the items into the existing array, without
        * creating a new array (so we keep the reference).
        */
        Array.prototype.push.apply(groups, data.response.items);

        /* The return statement is optional here */
        return { results: data.response };
      }
    });

  return {
    results: groups
  }
```

Comment: @VaIleNain, but wouldn't the `return { results:items };` statement be fired long time before the `function(filteredItems)`? Isn't it the point of AJAX calls? Or am i missing something here?

Comment: @VaILeNain, i've just tried it and it worked as i expected. `return { results:items };` is firing before the filtering ajax call. If you need the full code I can update my main post

Comment: yes, the return statement will be executed long before the second ajax call, but the object it returns (e.g. `{results: items}`) will be updated after the ajax call because we keep a reference to it.

Comment: @VaILeNain, i see. But the object has been already returned at this moment, right? So what difference would it make that it will be updated if it is already returned and select field is already populated with initial (unfiltered) data? 

I've tried your idea and it doesn't change anything. See my updated answer.

Comment: your update doesn't work either. It shows empty results. And I don't know what info to provide you. At the moment I've found another js plugin (selectize.js) with which I've managed to solve my problem using `$.when( $.ajax({ ... }).then(function(content) { $.ajax({ ... }) }) )`.